Webpack dynamic import and copyplugin
I have a bunch of json files that are imported in my code through dynamic import (code splitting)
    const hash = simpleHash(`${language}.${customerId}`)
    const clientTranslations = await import(
    /* webpackChunkName: "client_translation-[request]" */
    /* webpackMode: "lazy" */
      `../../../translations/client_translations_hashed/${hash}.json`
    )

However, the files in the /client_translations_hashed folder are placed there by the webpack.CopyPlugin, that reads json files from another location in my repo, and applies a hashing to ${language}.${customerId}, the same that the import uses.
In short, the use case is we deploy for multiple clients, but we want to have only one build. We dont want one client to see translations for the other clients or see the filename of the json for the other clients. That's why we hash it. It's not strong security, but it's Good Enough (TM).
   new CopyPlugin({
      patterns: [{
        from: '../common_packages/assets/translations/client_translations/*.json',
        to: ({ absoluteFilename }) => {
          const filename = path.basename(absoluteFilename, path.extname(absoluteFilename))
          if (!filename) {
            throw new Error(`Error whilst trying to create hashed version of ${absoluteFilename}...`)
          }
          const hashed = simpleHash(filename)
          return `../../../common_packages/assets/translations/client_translations_hashed/${hashed}.json`
        },
      }],
    }),

The problem that we are facing is that it seems that Webpack seems to inspect the directories for dynamic imports before the CopyPlugin is allowed to run. Because when we start from a clean situation, ie an empty client_translations_hashed folder, the client_translation-[request].js files that are to be imported dynamically are not generated.
When I run webpack a second time (so when the client_translation_hashed files have been copied from the last time webpack was run) it works.
Ideally, I would like to run webpack only once.
